# MVC 5 WebApi Action returning different object types depending on the route

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET MVC 5 with WebApi:

Is it possible to return different object types from a Controller's Action depending on the route used to access the Action?

I have the following at the WebApiConfig routing register:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiAMX",
            routeTemplate: "api/AMX/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

So, the idea is:

If i choose the "api/" route, the Action should return an object of type "A", but if i choose "api/AMX", it shouold returns type "B".

I know there are attributes like "RoutePrefix" or "Route", but that would force me to implement two Actions, one for each route path; something like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public IHttpActionResult ActionA(){
    return new A();
}

[RoutePrefix("api/AMX")]
public IHttpActionResult ActionB(){
    return new B();
}
```

And what i'd like to do is to check the route path inside the Action to return the proper type depending on the route.

Why do i want to implement something like that?

Because i have two types of ModelView objects (A and B in the examples): one to return if the caller of the API is an AMX device, and another to respond to the rest of the callers.
But, in either case, i have to search the database, and with the data returned compose an "standard" ModelView or an "AMX" ModelView, depending on the caller.

So i'm searching for something like:

```
public IHttpActionResult Action(int id)
{
    Patient patient = patientRepository.GetFirstOrDefault(p => p.PatientId == id);
    if(route == "/api")
    {
        return new Ok(new A{Name = patient.Name});
    }
    else if(route == "/api/AMX")
    {
        return new Ok(new B{AMXPatientName = patient.Name});
    }
}
```

I think that one good solution would be to check the route and compose the object depending on it, but if it is some kind of aberration, please teach me the proper way to implement it... Maybe just implementing different Actions, but in that case i would have to duplicate all the code before the "return", like the database call in the example.

Thank you!

Comment: I fail to understand why you want to check the route inside the action. That is completely against how Web API routes work.

Comment: Thanks for responding, i have updated the answer with somo more info.